# Error on AJAX call PHP function with JSON return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to develop a News Ticker using three technologies: PHP, Javascript and AJAX. 
First, I made a PHP function `getFeed()` to fetch data from News websites on an Array, then I made a JSON return using this code: `echo json_encode($articles, true);`

Secondly, I aim to use AJAX and Javascript to make repeated calls to `getFeed()` function, here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javasript">
    var xmlhttp=false;
    function begin() {

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                var jsonContent=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                displayT(jsonContent);

            }
        };

     // rssnews.inc.php contain the getFeed() function

        xmlhttp.open('GET','rssnews.inc.php', true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
     // displayT(content) function display the JSON element
        function displayT(content){
            var out = "";
            var i;

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                out += '<h4><a href="' + arr[i].link+ '">' + 
                arr[i].title + '</a></h4><br>';
            }
            document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = out;
        }
</script>
```

On the HTML page, I have the following components a button (`id="start"`) - on click execute `begin()` function, a div container (`id="Ticker"`) and a div (`id="item"`) for display data with AJAX

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="start" onclick="begin();"> START </button>
</form>

<div  id= "ticker" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 500px; weight:600px;">

    <div id="item">
        <!-- I want to display the fetched data by 4 items at a specific time Interval-->           
    </div>

</div>
```

When I click on the start button, I don't get the json data.

How can I solve this problem and how can I ensure that this AJAX calls is the most appropriate way to my Ticker. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is essentially saying you don't have a file by this name, in this location.  Make sure the browser can find rssnews.inc.php.

Comment: Thank you @user5855223 but the rssnews.inc.php exist and before using AJAX was running normally

Comment: Your browser is looking for it at http://localhost/rss/rssnews.inc.php and cannot find it there.

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @user5855223 well I solve the problem of the path to rssnews.inc.php, but now i cannot get the fetched data

Answer (score 0):

The error is essentially saying that the file you are trying to GET with you AJAX call, does not exist at the specified location *(which is `http://localhost/rss/rssnews.inc.php`)*.

You are using a **Relative path**, which searches for 'rssnews.inc.php' in the same folder. To go up to the parent directory, use `../`.

Or use an **Absolute path**, as in `http://localhost/rss/rssnews.inc.php`.  *(Replace with absolute path to your PHP script)*

### Update

*(after HTTP 401 solved)*

`displayT` function is taking `content` as input, and is then reffering to `arr`, which is not defined.

Assuming `content` is actually an array containing your data in the desired format, replace `arr` with `content`:

```
function displayT(content){
        var out = "";
        var i;

        for(i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            out += '<h4><a href="' + content[i].link+ '">' + 
            content[i].title + '</a></h4><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you brother that solve the problem, but the data are not displayed when I click on the button

Comment: Thank you so much for your corrections but any data has shown :(

Comment: Remember that you are using `JSON.parse()` to parse the response text, hence it's no longer as returned from `rssnews.inc.php`  You may want to `console.log(content)` to: A) Make sure you are getting the expected data. B) See the structure of data returned, and then figure out how to display it correctly.

Comment: I have did what you suggest but i don't get any data when I use console.log(content)

Comment: To make sure your `displayT` function is being called, put `console.log('content: ' + content);` inside of `displayT` function.  If 'content: ' is logged to the console but nothing else, then you know your function is being called.  This would leave us with your initial problem solved, and then you would have to look into rssnews.inc.php to fix any bugs in the script.

Comment: thank you, nothing appear on the onsole log, that's mean that I have a problem on the PHP script ?!